# LibGDX: setScrollbarsVisible Not works

Tags: libgdx

I have a `ScrollPane` and I want to hide the scrollbar:

```
scrollPane.setScrollbarsVisible(false);
```

But not works!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

setScrollbarsVisible(boolean visible)
Shows or hides the scrollbars for when using setFadeScrollBars(boolean).

You should try using it in combination with this method.